# Elliptic Curve based blind signature implementation

Tags: elliptic-curves, protocol-design, reference-request, dsa, blind-signature

I want to use Elliptic Curve based blind signature scheme for my research.

There is no proper implementation of ECC-based blind signatures.

Can someone describe to me which things I need to follow when implementing this?

Comment: there is not a single blind signature scheme usable in the ECC setting, but various schemes. Which scheme do you want to use and what are your problems with the scheme?

Comment: Could you able to tell me available scehemes?

Comment: you are required to do (literature) research on your own before asking here (we do not answer "reference requests" here). However, you may find some examples [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2424/which-blind-signature-schemes-exist-and-how-do-they-compare). Basically, any existing ElGamal, Schnorr, DSA type blind signature scheme can be used in the ECC setting.

Comment: @DrLecter Actually, [**we do answer them**](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/tags/reference-request/info)… but such requests indeed should not boil down to a “let me google that for you” kind of thing, which is why you're correct in pointing towards a [**literature research**](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8316/12164).

Comment: @e-sushi yes, that is the message I wanted to deliver ;)

Comment: @DrLecter Let’s just say I needed an excuse to drop that “literature research” link in here. ;)